# Tesseract - How can I recognize numbers in box?

Tags: c#, numbers, character, ocr, tesseract

I have a image that you can see. But Tesseract recognize it is no text. How could I make Tesseract learn that this has numbers and can extract from image?

[image: Image inside box]

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Well, the most general question you can get. Read their **Overview of the Tesseract OCR Engine** and read other documentation with code examples http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseracticdar2007.pdf

Comment: I have tried with cut it in to boxes but Tesseract cannot recognize it easily (fail 90%)